# grunt-autoshot 'cannot call method 'createPage' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'd like to get [grunt-autoshot](https://github.com/Ferrari/grunt-autoshot) working to take screenshots of my project, but there seems to be one small hitch I can't find.
I've reconfigured the **grunt.initConfig** commands different ways and can't seem to get this to work.  this is all locally hosted, the server is loading properly and i can see my sample files ('index.html') when [grunt server](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) is turned on . Below is what I'm using now based off the [example page](https://github.com/Ferrari/grunt-autoshot)

> Error: **'Fatal error: Cannot call method 'createPage' of undefined'**

```
autoshot: {
        default_options: {
            options: {
                // necessary config
                path: 'screenshots/',
                local: {
                    path: './test',
                    port: 9000,
                    files: [{
                        src: 'index.html',
                        dest: 'index.jpg'
                    }]
                },
                viewport: [
                    '320x480', '480x320', '384x640', '640x384', '602x963', '963x602', '600x960', '960x600', '800x1280', '1280x800', '768x1024', '1024x768'
                ]
            },
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install PhantomJS.

If you're on a Mac you can do:

```
brew update && brew install phantomjs
```

Otherwise visit http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Comment: I have the same error message even though I have PhantomJS installed:
`$phantomjs -v  
1.9.2`

Answer (score 0):

I was working with a friend and we just run into the same problem.

It looks like it's because of the phantomjs' version. I was using 1.9.2 and I was getting the same error, download and install 1.9.0 and it'll work (it did for me) you can download it from here: https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/downloads/detail?name=phantomjs-1.9.0-macosx.zip&can=1&q=